# WCF Service Hosted in IIS System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service, hosted in IIS returning the following error (when trying to call a method or even just browse to the service definition):

> "Service not available"

The error log shows a bit more detail:

> An unhandled exception occurred and
>   the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID:
>   /LM/w3svc/1/ROOT/C_wcfService
>
> Process ID: 4696
>
> Exception:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
>
> Message: External component has thrown
>   an exception.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was being caused b the Execute Permissions in IIS. The virutual directory was set to "Scripts only" and changing this to "Scripts and Executables" has resolved the issue. I'm not sure how you're supposed to get to this answer from the original error (but fiddling for a while seems to work!)

Answer (score 1):

Try recycling the AppPool that is hosting the service (an `iisreset` will work as well but is more invasive).  Without more information it is hard to say what is wrong but recycling the AppPool will at least fix the immediate problem.